# Converting DTS to flac results in bigger file size & more bit-dept than source

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion

Am I doing something wrong?

The command I ran was `ffmpeg -i sample.mkv -acodec flac -vcodec copy flac.mkv`

The original file had 16 bits DTS and the resulting FLAC 24 bits, and the file is +1 GB bigger, while everywhere I read says flac should be smaller than DTS.

What is the correct command to convert proprietary lossless formats to FLAC, while keeping the original settings and getting the smallest file size possible ?

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg's FLAC encoder defaults to 24 bits (padded and stored as 32).

Override it like this,

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mkv -acodec flac -sample_fmt s16 -vcodec copy flac.mkv
```

Comment: I don't understand much about this stuff. But won't that be bad for all other input that is not 16 bits? I would like something that just mirror the source settings ( bit depth, channels, etc ). Is there any benefit in 24 bits vs 16 ?

Comment: If the source audio is 16 bits then there's no benefit to encoding it as 24 bits. Your input appears to be either >16 bits or 16-bits stored as 32-bit floating point, hence FLAC is selecting 24 bits output.

Comment: And why the file size is higher while should be smaller than the DTS track? How can I make ffmpeg just use the input bit depth ? I want to use this command for other files too

Comment: FLAC only supports two bit depths - 16 or 24 (stored as 32). If the input is 16 bit or lower, then 16 bit output is chosen, else 24 bit. So, your original command is fine. When the input is 16 bits but stored as 32 bits then ffmpeg will select 24 bits output. In which case, setting output sample depth, like in my answer, is needed to encode as 16 bits.

Comment: will FLAC always mirror the channels / etc? and still, why I am not getting a smaller file size than the DTS track? Will be quality loss if input file is over 16 bit and I encode as 16 bit flac?

Comment: *will FLAC always mirror the channels / etc?* --> upto 8, yes. And the layout? if it's one of the standard layouts - yes. A lossless encode of a compressed stream will always be larger unless the source audio is "simple" or was compressed with a very high bitrate. Since the lossless aims for perfect fidelity, it can't settle for good-enough signal prediction.

Comment: For consumer use, 16 bit is good enough, regardless of source depth.

Comment: thanks dude. But see here, https://losen.win/articles/convert-dts-hd-ma-truehd-lpcm-to-flac-is-it-worth-it/convert-dts-hd-ma-to-flac.html ... According to everything I should be getting a smaller or nearly equal file size. not a bigger size...

Comment: Those are the lossless DTS varieties. Show your full log output.

Comment: what is your telegram @Gyan I want to hire you

Answer (score 2):

You also need to reduce the number of channels ommiting the LFE:

```
ffmpeg -i 'input.wav' -acodec flac -sample_fmt s16 -ac 2 -vol 425 -ar 44100 'output.flac'
```

Of course you may ommit:

```
-ar 44100
```

if the original file is already the sample rate you want.
If your filenames contain spaces enclose those in '' as I did, otherwise you may ommit that.

There are better approaches yet non-standard in terms of combining channels. For music I have found this down-mix approach to fit my needs and satisfy my ears:

```
ffmpeg -i 'input.wav' -acodec flac -sample_fmt s16 -af "pan=stereo|FL=0.35*FC+0.707*FL+0.5*BL+0.25*LFE|FR=0.35*FC+0.707*FR+0.5*BR+0.25*LFE" -ar 44100 'output.flac'
```

Coefficients have been scaled so that there is no clipping. Basic process consists in mixing -9dB of center, -3dB of each channel front, -6dB of each channel rear and -12dB of sub-woofer. This is non standard yet sounds good for music. Standard (-ac2) is -3dB center, -3db front and rear and no sub-woofer.

More information may be found [here](https://ajoliveira.com/ajoliveira/uk/audio/dts.php).

Comment: Code formatting for the command required - From review

Comment: This is a perfect response for my in what respects to audio files. It even have the choice of select a simpler approach or a more advanced one including down-mixing of 5.1 one channels to stereo. Good work!